# FFMPEG. Read frame, process it, put it to output video. Copy sound stream unchanged

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I want to apply processing to a video clip with sound track, extract and process frame by frame and write result to output file. Number of frames, size of frame and speed remains unchanged in output clip. Also I want to keep the same audio track as I have in source.

I can read clip, decode frames and process then using opencv. Audio packets are also writes fine. I'm stuck on forming output video stream.

The minimal runnable code I have for now (sorry it not so short, but cant do it shorter):

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc  avcodec_alloc_frame
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static void log_packet(const AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVPacket *pkt, const char *tag)
{
    AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;

    char buf1[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->pts);
    char buf2[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->dts);
    char buf3[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->duration);

    char buf4[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_time_string(buf1, pkt->pts, time_base);
    char buf5[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_time_string(buf1, pkt->dts, time_base);
    char buf6[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
    av_ts_make_time_string(buf1, pkt->duration, time_base);

    printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
        buf1, buf4,
        buf2, buf5,
        buf3, buf6,
        pkt->stream_index);

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVPacket pkt;
    AVFrame *pFrame = NULL;
    AVFrame *pFrameRGB = NULL;
    int frameFinished = 0;
    pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

    const char *in_filename, *out_filename;
    int ret, i;
    in_filename = "../../TestClips/Audio Video Sync Test.mp4";
    out_filename = "out.mp4";

    // Initialize FFMPEG
    av_register_all();
    // Get input file format context
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, in_filename, 0, 0)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file '%s'", in_filename);
        goto end;
    }
    // Extract streams description
    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        goto end;
    }
    // Print detailed information about the input or output format,
    // such as duration, bitrate, streams, container, programs, metadata, side data, codec and time base.
    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, in_filename, 0);

    // Allocate an AVFormatContext for an output format.
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    // The output container format.
    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    // Allocating output streams
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
        if (!out_stream)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }
        ret = avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context\n");
            goto end;
        }
        out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
        if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        {
            out_stream->codec->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        }
    }

    // Show output format info
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);

    // Open output file
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
            goto end;
        }
    }
    // Write output file header
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Search for input video codec info
    AVCodec *in_codec = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* avctx = nullptr;

    int video_stream_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->coder_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            video_stream_index = i;
            avctx = ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec;
            in_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(avctx->codec_id);
            if (!in_codec)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "in codec not found\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Search for output video codec info
    AVCodec *out_codec = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* o_avctx = nullptr;

    int o_video_stream_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ofmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->coder_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            o_video_stream_index = i;
            o_avctx = ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec;
            out_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(o_avctx->codec_id);
            if (!out_codec)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "out codec not found\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // openCV pixel format
    AVPixelFormat pFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    // Data size
    int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(pFormat, avctx->width, avctx->height);
    // allocate buffer 
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
    // fill frame structure
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, pFormat, avctx->width, avctx->height);
    // frame area
    int y_size = avctx->width * avctx->height;
    // Open input codec
    avcodec_open2(avctx, in_codec, NULL);
    // Main loop
    while (1)
    {
        AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        log_packet(ifmt_ctx, &pkt, "in");
        // copy packet 
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;

        log_packet(ofmt_ctx, &pkt, "out");
        if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_index)
        {
            avcodec_decode_video2(avctx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &pkt);
            if (frameFinished)
            {
                struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
                img_convert_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(NULL,
                    avctx->width,
                    avctx->height,
                    avctx->pix_fmt,
                    avctx->width,
                    avctx->height,
                    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                    SWS_BICUBIC,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
                    ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->data,
                    ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->linesize,
                    0,
                    avctx->height,
                    ((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB)->data,
                    ((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB)->linesize);

                sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);

                // Do some image processing
                cv::Mat img(pFrame->height, pFrame->width, CV_8UC3, pFrameRGB->data[0],false);
                cv::GaussianBlur(img,img,Size(5,5),3);
                cv::imshow("Display", img);
                cv::waitKey(5);
                // --------------------------------
                // Transform back to initial format
                // --------------------------------
                img_convert_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(NULL,
                    avctx->width,
                    avctx->height,
                    AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                    avctx->width,
                    avctx->height,
                    avctx->pix_fmt,
                    SWS_BICUBIC,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
                    ((AVPicture*)pFrameRGB)->data,
                    ((AVPicture*)pFrameRGB)->linesize,
                    0,
                    avctx->height,
                    ((AVPicture *)pFrame)->data,
                    ((AVPicture *)pFrame)->linesize);
                    // --------------------------------------------
                    // Something must be here
                    // --------------------------------------------
                    //
                    // Write fideo frame (How to write frame to output stream ?)
                    //
                    // --------------------------------------------
                     sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
            }

        }
        else // write sound frame
        {
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
        }
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
            break;
        }
        // Decrease packet ref counter
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    // close output 
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    }
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR_EOF)
    {
        char buf_err[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = { 0 };
        av_make_error_string(buf_err, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, ret);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred: %s\n", buf_err);
        return 1;
    }

    avcodec_close(avctx);
    av_free(pFrame);
    av_free(pFrameRGB);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must set up a codex context and encode the frame. Then write it using `av_interleaved_write_frame`

Comment: Does not works for me, encoding does not gives errors, but written frame is empty, only sound present in result clip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code segfaults in my case. Initializing the output codec context seems to fix it. The code below works for me but I didn't test the OpenCV stuff as I don't have the lib installed.

Get the codec context:

```
// Search for output video codec info
AVCodec *out_codec = NULL;
AVCodecContext* o_avctx = NULL;

int o_video_stream_index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < ofmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
{
    if (ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->coder_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        o_video_stream_index = i;        
        out_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_id);
        o_avctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(out_codec);

        o_avctx->height = avctx->height;
        o_avctx->width = avctx->width;
        o_avctx->sample_aspect_ratio = avctx->sample_aspect_ratio;            
        if (out_codec->pix_fmts)
            o_avctx->pix_fmt = out_codec->pix_fmts[0];
        else
            o_avctx->pix_fmt = avctx->pix_fmt;
        o_avctx->time_base = avctx->time_base;

        avcodec_open2(o_avctx, out_codec, NULL);
    }
}
```

Encode and write:

```
// Main loop
while (1)
{

...

if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_index)
{        
    avcodec_decode_video2(avctx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &pkt);

    if (frameFinished)
    {
        ...
        // --------------------------------------------
        // Something must be here
        // --------------------------------------------
        int got_packet = 0;
        AVPacket enc_pkt = { 0 };
        av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);        

        avcodec_encode_video2(o_avctx, &enc_pkt, pFrame, &got_packet);
        av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);

        ....

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed code as you provide. but it throws access violation error on av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt); command.  'Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC514678B1 (avcodec-57.dll) in OpenCV_FFMPEG_Sample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000000A0.'  Seems I confused here. Could you place full minimal runnable code here please ?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Sure, here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/gBUxKcmQ) and [diff](http://pastebin.com/WUrE6MHg). Tested with ffmpeg git head and an mp4 containing H.264/AAC streams. Please note that I didn't fix all the code issues like deprecation, proper cleanup etc though and, as I said, didn't check the OpenCV part.

Comment: Thank you for code, it works, but only if avcodec_encode_video2(o_avctx, &enc_pkt, pFrame, &got_packet); uses pFrame as parameter. If I trying to encode pFrameRGB it fails at av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt); line.

Comment: If I got your code right you're using `sws_scale` at the end to put the result back in pFrame. So why encode pFrameRGB instead?

Comment: If you want to use RGB24 check if the encoder supports it and configure it to use this pixel format instead.

Comment: Finally it writes frames! Thank you very much!

Comment: With avi as output it works fine.If I use mp4  it writes black screens. But it ok for me now, just as note.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov mp4, avi are just container formats. You have to check what codecs they use and convert the frame data accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I'll check this, thanks. I also suspect frame sizes are matter here. In mp4 case it changes image size, with respect to original video.

Answer (score 0):

you should assign processed frame's packets information to your Original packets then pass it to `av_interleaved_write_frame`

Comment: Not sure I understand you, I tried to copy data from encoded processed packets to output packets, but still black screen video on output.

Comment: try with `av_interleaved_write_uncoded_frame` without encoding frame. According to documentation it should help you otherwise i think now way.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, but tried this way also, with no success.